# Assign max-height to inner element after toggle

Tags: javascript, html, css

many thanks to anyone who can help me solving the issue

Here is HTML and JS:

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("razvernut");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function(){
        this.classList.toggle("razvorot");
        var panel = document.getElementsByClassName('sub-menu');
        if (panel.style.maxHeight){
            panel.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
          panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
        } 
    }
}
```

```html
<li class="razvernut">
    <span class="span"></span>
    <span class="otherspan"></span>
    <a>Show ul.sub-menu with 0 max-height</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">...</ul>
</li>
```

My skill in js is quite low, please tell me where is the mistake as script cant define the .sub-menu within the page :\

Comment: Could you provide some error message? Maybe the only problem is that you should handle the panel as an array like you did in case of acc.

Comment: Dij'a answer seems correct in my opinion. Alternatively, you can assign an id to submenu <ul> and use 'getElementByID` function. Ids in Javascript are unique so it might make more sense to use them when you have only one element you expect to get.

Comment: @jrook wordpress gives no chance to assign id to submenu item :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a list of elements, you can either iterate over the list and use each element inside the loop, or in your case you can use panel[0].

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("razvernut");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
acc[i].onclick = function(){
    this.classList.toggle("razvorot");
    var panel = document.getElementsByClassName('sub-menu');
    if (panel[0].style.maxHeight){
        panel[0].style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel[0].style.maxHeight = panel[0].scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
}
}
```

```html
<li class="razvernut">
<span class="span"></span>
<span class="otherspan"></span>
<a>Show ul.sub-menu with 0 max-height</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">...</ul>
</li>
```